# can I use 'show SQL query' from crystal report and use in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I got some crystal reports, these are developed by someone but now I am migrating to SSRS. So when i go to 'show SQL query' from crystal reports it is showing some query but i can't understand properly where these columns coming from. Is there anyway to know exact SQL query so that i can use it in sql server to generate data sets for SSRS.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [Sql Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) against your database server to see the exact Sql that Crystal Reports is running to generate the report.

Sql Profiler is a tool that comes with Sql Server (under Performance Tools in your Sql Server programs) that shows every Sql statement hitting the database. Run a trace on your Sql Server through Sql Profiler then run your report and Sql Profiler will show you the exact Sql statements that your Crystal report is running against the database.

Comment: Hi Chris Lätta, yes it worked fine thanks for the help..god bless you

Comment: If this solves your problem you should accept this as the answer (green tick) and upvote it (up arrow) so that the next person searching for this knows that this solution solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be split the query manully and see the select and where clause using or if you have access to database run the query over the database to check what all columns it is returning